# Why does fan speed increase when connecting to wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, fan, cooling

I have noticed that whenever my laptop is connecting to a wifi connection, fan speed momentarily increases. After I enter the wifi password and the computer connects successfully, the fan speed decreases to normal again.

Why does this happen? I don't think that any processor-intensive task is carried on when connecting to wifi which causes heating. I've noticed this effect on both Windows 10 and Manjaro on the same machine.

Edit:

The fan starts before I enter my password. Until I connect successfully (after I tap the connect to wifi button), I see plasmashell  consuming around 54% cpu which dies off to 4% after I connect. I am currently using Manjaro 18.1.3 Juhraya (KDE 5.64.0 / Plasma 5.17.3) with kernel version 4.19.85-1 if that matters.

Comment: Does it increase _before_ you enter the password, or immediately after? Have you checked which process, if any, shows up at the top of CPU usage list?

Comment: @grawity I've edited the question. Please see it.

Comment: *Why does this happen?* Possible sequence of events: Wifi module enables scan mode - much power - heating - increasing temperature in case - MB detects this - increase fan speed - successfull connect - WiFi module in transfer mode - less power - less heat - decreasing temperature - MB detects this - decrease fan speed.

Comment: Try to perform the data transfer when all channel transfer rate capacity is used - does the fan speed is inceasing?

Comment: Scan mode is somewhat unlikely. Sounds more like a Plasma Shell bug.

Comment: @grawity The OP *noticed this effect on both Windows 10 and Manjaro on the same machine*. Do you still think it's a Plasma Shell bug?